# Use javascript with POST method

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

sorry for that, but I need your help on something :
I need to get my values in javascript, as it was filled in my form, and I have no clue how to do it, as whenever I tried to search, it was made for people with at least some understanding of javascript. I have none, but tried my best, the results of my efforts are here :

```
function validateForm() {
var x = form.('form').elements["sexe"];
 if (x == null) {
  alert("Un sexe doit être sélectionné");
  return false;
 }
}
```

I need to get it done by POST method, as get isn't allowed :

```
<form action="Monformulairedereferencement." method="post" id="sexe" name="form">
        <div id="BlueBorder1">
            sexe
            <input type="radio" id="Homme" name="sexe" value="Homme" aria-checked="true">
                <label for="Homme">Homme</label>
            <input type="radio" id="Femme" name="sexe" value="Femme" aria-checked="true">
                <label for="Femme">Femme</label>
            <input type="radio" id="Autre" name="sexe" value="Autre" aria-checked="true">
                <label for="Autre">Autre</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="civilite">civilite</label>
                <select name="civilite" id="civilite">
                    <option value="M.">M.</option>
                    <option value="Mme.">Mme.</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="nom">nom</label>
                <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" minlength="2">
        </div>
        <div id="BlueBorder2">
            <label for="email">email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="telephone">telephone</label>
                <input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="website">website</label>
                <input type="url" name="website" id="website">
        </div>
        <div id="BlueBorder3">
            <label for="datedenaissance">date de naissance</label>
                <input type="date" id="datedenaissance" name="date de naissance">
        </div>
        <div>
            hobbies
            <input type="checkbox" id="Jeuxvideo" name="hobbies">
                <label for="Jeuxvideo">Jeux video</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Cinema" name="hobbies">
                <label for="Cinema">Cinema</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Lecture" name="hobbies">
                <label for="Lecture">Lecture</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Sport" name="hobbies">
                <label for="Sport">Sport</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Informatique" name="hobbies">
                <label for="Informatique">Informatique</label>
        </div>
            <input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" value="my first website">
        <div>
            <label for="validation">validation</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Envoyer le formulaire" id="validation">
```

If you have any clue of what isn't working or anything, then I'll gladly accept it. My only goal is to improve and I'm currently very bad.
Have a nice day and thanks for passing by :)

Comment: As a fist step you need to call `validateForm`. Try learning/doing things step by step

Comment: I've voted to close this question as "too broad/needs more focus", because while the question is "how do I access my form data", the code `form.('form').elements["sexe"]` suggests that an answer also needs to cover a crash course on function calls, arrays and event handlers, and that is too big of a scope for a question.

Comment: Thanks for that guys.
What do I need to focus on to get a good handle on this subject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a value of a text input in JS, you need to get this input then get its value.

So for example: `<input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" minlength="2">`
to get this input value in JS, you have to follow 2 steps:

1. Assign the input element to variable -> `let nom = document.getElementById('nom');`
2. Get the value of this input element -> `let nomValue = nom.value;`

The previous approach can be applied to any text input (text, password, email, ...), textarea, & select menu

For checkboxes or radio buttons, you need to check if they are checked or not, for example: `<input type="radio" id="Homme" name="sexe" value="Homme" >` to check this, follow 2 steps:

1. Assign checkbox or radio button to a variable -> `let Homme = document.getElementById('Homme');`
2. Check if this checkbox or radio button is checked -> `if (Homme.checked) {console.log('Checked')} else {console.log('Checked')}`

For simple validation approach for your code, follow this snippet:

```
<!-- HTML Form -->
<form action="x.php" method="post" id="sexe" name="form">
  <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" minlength="2">
  <input type="radio" id="Homme" name="sexe" value="Homme">
  <input type="submit" value='Send' >
</form>

<!-- Validation Script -->
<script>
  // Get Form Itself 
  let myForm = document.getElementById('sexe');

  // Add Event To Form On Submit, Trigger The Validation Funcntion
  myForm.addEventListener('submit', validateForm)

  // Validate Form Function
  function validateForm(e) {
    // Get All Inputs In Your Form 
    let nom = document.getElementById('nom');      // Text Input
    let Homme = document.getElementById('Homme');  // Radio Input

    // Check Text Input Value If Not Empty
    if(nom.value === '') {
      // Prevent Form Submition
      e.preventDefault();
      // Alert Error Message
      alert('Name Can Not Be Empty');
    } 
    // Check If Radio Button Not Checked
    else if (!Homme.checked) {
      // Prevent Form Submition
      e.preventDefault();
      // Alert Error Message
      alert('Radio Button Is Required');
    }
    // If The Previous Two Validation Steps Is Done And No Errors, The Form Will Be Sent
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the easiest way to grab the value from the form is to use **addEventListners** with Submit event. It looks likes an ***element.addEventListner('submit',function);***

```js
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form'); //we have selected whole form
function formSubmitted(){
  const emails = document.getElementsById('email');//select the email section 
  let emailValue = emails.value // it will give you the value of email after submitting 
}

forms.addEventListner('submit',formSubmitted);//eventlistern which run after submiting the data in form
```